# Как правильно спроектировать лайки в API?

Tags: api, rest, проектирование

Проектирую REST API. Имеется некая сущность (например, пост), которой пользователи будут ставить лайки.

Задачи для API:

- поставить лайк посту
- снять лайк
- посмотреть список пользователей, лайкнувших пост
- посмотреть посты, которые лайкнул пользователь
- возможно добавятся еще..

Вижу 2 варианта реализации.

**Первый:**

- POST /posts/{id_post}/likes - поставить лайк
- DELETE /posts/{id_post}/likes?user_id={user_id} - снять лайк
- GET /posts/{id_post}/likes - получить список лайков поста
- GET /users/{id_user}/likes - получить список лайков пользователя

**Второй:**

- POST /likes - поставить лайк
- DELETE /likes?user_id={user_id}&post_id={post_id} - снять лайк
- GET /likes?post_id={post_id} - получить список лайков поста
- GET /likes?user_id={user_id} - получить список лайков пользователя

Какой вариант предпочтительнее и почему? Или может есть более правильные варианты?

PS: если кто знает годную литературу или статью на эту тему, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET    | /posts/{post}/likes # список лайков поста
GET    | /users/{user}/likes # список лайков юзера
POST   | /posts/{post}/likes # поставить лайк
DELETE | /posts/{post}/likes # снять лайк
```

Смысла передавать `id` пользователя нет, т.к. вы его можете получить с сессии или что вы там используете (для удаления/добавления лайка).

Comment: Насчет сессии не понял, как из нее получить данные? Вернее, как их туда положить для начала? И что вообще, подразумевается под сессией? Прошу сильно не бить, опыта в разработке API маловато.

Comment: @LIFED все зависит от ЯП который вы используете. В PHP к примеру данные авторизованого пользователя могут храниться в сесси, и с нее мы можем получить id пользователя.

Comment: С авторизацией я к сожалению не разобрался еще. Можете подсказать стратегию для авторизации? Использую как раз PHP. Думал передавать id пользователя или - мой самый умный вариант - токен авторизированного пользователя. Сама авторизация по сути просто скрипт, который проверяет корректность логина и пароля, и, если делать с токенами, возвращает токен авторизации, который я сохраню где-то на клиенте для последующего использования в параметрах API. Я что-то делаю не так?)

Comment: @LIFED передавать id пользователя - очень плохой вариант. Токен - мысль верная, но вместо того чтобы придумывать что-то свое почитайте что такое JWT, библиотека для работы с ним в PHP есть.
Если вы используете какой-то фреймворк - посмотрите в докуметации, скорее всего там уже предложено решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @LIFED, если это ответ на ваш вопрос, то отметьте его решением, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, я не забыл :)
Спасибо за наводку, узнал очень много нового и интересного

Answer (score 0):

А почему **/posts/{id_post}/likes** ?

Лайк то один, на мой взляд лучше:

**POST** */post/{id}/like* - ставим лайк/снимаем лайк (реализовать логику проверки, лайкнут ли пост ранее)

**GET** */post/{id}/likes* - получаем лайки поста

**GET** */user/{id}/likes* - получаем лайки пользователя.